# How to get focused VisualElement in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, focus

i have to show more than 10 ContentPages in a CarouselPage in xamarin, and in each ContentPage there are many Labels, Buttons ,Entries. so how can i current focused VisualElement.

I found events [VisualElement.Focused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.focused?view=xamarin-forms),[VisualElement.Unfocused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.unfocused?view=xamarin-forms),[VisualElement.FocusChangeRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.focuschangerequested?view=xamarin-forms).

But none can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although **VisualElement** has **Focused** and **UnFocused** event , not all controls
will response because the events are belong to the superclass . And it also due to different platforms .

For example , the **Focused** and **UnFocused** event of **WebView** will work on iOS but not on Android .

In your case , **Label** and **Button** will not invoke the events in most cases. **Entry** will been focused when in edit mode (input) and been unfocused when end editing  .

So , if you do want to get current focused element , you could define a property in ContentPage .

```
public object FocusedElement;
```

```
private void FocusEvent(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
   FocusedElement = sender; //sender here is the element , like label or entry
}

private void UnfocusEvent(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
   FocusedElement = null;
}
```

#### in xaml

Define the **Focused** and **UnFocused** event of each Element

```
 <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Focused="FocusEvent" Unfocused="Label_Unfocused"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


        <Button  Focused="FocusEvent" Unfocused="UnfocusEvent" Text="111"/>

        <Entry   Focused="FocusEvent" Unfocused="UnfocusEvent" HeightRequest="50"  WidthRequest="100" />
```

Comment: yes, this works, but i have to add events Focused and Unfocused for all views. Is there another solution?

Comment: I think it is the best solution . Or you can define a basic class of button ,label and entry .